# Do these memtest86 results indicate a defective memory module?

Tags: memory, diagnostic, ddr3, memtest86+

I just ran [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) and I received these results (the picture is from the 4th test of the second pass):

[image]

Obviously something really bad is happening. I guess that red row should not be there. Also columns Pass and Errors are alarming. The only test which passed was 8th test in the 1st run (Modulo 20, random number).

Does this result mean that one of my six RAM modules is damaged and should be replaced?

**Edit:**

I followed advice from andyFX and performed several additional tests. My motherboard has 6 dimm sockets A2 A1 B2 B1 C2 C1. Based on allowed configurations described in motherboar's user guide I did these tests:

1. Module 1 and Module 2 (sockets A1 and B1)
2. Module 4 and Module 5 (sockets A1 and B1)
3. Module 3 and Module 6 (sockets A1 abd B1)
4. Module 1, Module 2 and Module 3 (sockets A1, B1 and C1)
5. Module 4, Module 5 and Module 6 (sockets A1, B1 and C1)
6. Module 4, Module 1, Module 2 and Module 3 (sockets A2, A1, B1 and C1)

All these tests were successful. Then I again performed test with all six modules but in this test I swaped modules in paired sockets A2 <-> A1 etc. The result is this:

[image]

Failling address has changed after swapping modules but it is the only change. Based on these tests I guess memory modules are OK, because they all worked when tested in pairs, triads and in single selected quaternion. How can I further diagnose source of this issue? Motherboard is ASUS P6T Deluxe V2 with Intel i7 920 processor. Memory modules are OCZ3P1600LV2G bought as two packages with three modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try your memory one by one and see if it is indeed a problem with your memory module or is something wrong with your bios settings or maybe motherboard. If only one module have this error you definitely need to change it.

Cheers.

EDIT:

Try setting your tRas to 24 (7-7-7-24). The lower this settings is the better is performance but can cause data corruption if is to lower... What is your memory voltage set to? 1.64?

Comment: I will try it. At the moment all my Bios settings are set to Auto. So I hope that voltage is 1.65V.

Comment: I change timings to 7-7-7-24 but the problem remains.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I haven't solve the problem yet and I will probably not solve it. It is strange that 1 single bit (as I understand results) is failing when all six modules run together but it haven't cause me any real problems yet.